# Задача Квадратное уравнение

Tags: python

Даны действительные числа a, b, c. Найдите все решения квадратного уравнения ax2 + bx + c = 0.
Даны три действительных числа, a не равно 0. 
Выведите два действительных числа, если уравнение имеет два корня, одно действительное число – при наличии одного корня. При отсутствии действительных корней ничего выводить не нужно.

Почему то пишет неправильное решение.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)
l = 2 * a

if d == 0:
    print(-b/(2*a))
elif d > 0:
    print((-b + (d**(1/2))) / l, (-b - (d**(1/2))) / l)
```

Comment: почему вы думаете, что корни - целые числа?

Comment: Два вопроса : 1) если правильно понимаю,  у вам и коэффициенты и вывод корней -.целочисленные.  Почему?  2) Если дискриминант будет отрицательным,  квадратный корень из него вычислится?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, тип переменных изменяется при получении нецелых чисел
квадратный корень вычисляется и получается комплексный тип

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но не очень помогло, подняли 1 балл...

Comment: а еще обрати внимание, что будет, если ввести a = 0

Comment: В условии подписано, что a не равно 0.

Comment: Еще пара замечаний.
объявлять переменные можно так:
```a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())```
незачем вычислять l до выяснения, будем ли мы его использовать
и последнее: на первое место нужно ставить те условия, которые выполняются чаще, что бы не было лишних проверок. d в основном > 0

Получился такой код
https://pastebin.com/2Q9JZPnd

Comment: Спасибо!! Учту.

Comment: @splash58, не корни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё дело в динамической типизации.
`d = (b**2) - (4*a*c)` -  тип переменной d - float/int

`d = d ** (1/2)` - а тут, когда вы попытались найти корень числа, если, оно отрицательное - d принимает тип "комплексное число".

То-есть если брать корень отриц. числа - питон даст число комплексное, которое уже другой тип данных, и которое нельзя сравнивать с 0.

Сравнивайте d с 0 до вычисления корня

Comment: Исправил, но не сильно помогло.

Comment: код исправления в студию.

Comment: А как полный код будет с выводом данных в терминале с целыми числами, не float?

Answer (score 1):

В условии сказано что бы вы вводили действительные числа(они могут быть целыми, вещественными и так далее) Вы же принимаете на вход только целые числа. Исправьте int(input()) на float(input()), возможно это вам поможет.

Comment: В чём разница между вещественными и действительными числами?